# Methods to differentiate between terrain

Tags: contour, comparison, volume, differences

I am not specialized in GIS.

I have some moisture contour maps, I want to compare each pair to trace the changes between either in a numeric way. I tried to get the mathematical difference between the corresponding values of each pair of maps and to calculate the ratio between volumes (Area * moisture content as a third dimension).

Are their more scientific methods to perform such comparisons?

I searched for "comparing terrain volumes" but it leads to nothing.

Comment: The easiest way is interpolating them to rasters of the same extent and cell size. Raster calculator (difference) will do the rest. If ArcGis is an option, I suggest using topo to raster tool for interpolation, it's the best when dealing with contours.

Comment: Many thanks @FelixIP for your answer, However, I use python in my work, I do not know about the raster calculator. Can you suggest native algorithms names so that I can search for them in python, or even I can implement them myself.

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-topo-to-raster-works.htm. Won't be easy to implement and you also need to find raster format comfortable to work with. Raster calculator is easy, you perform math on the same cell from 2 or more rasters.

Comment: ..and store result in output raster. You'll turn to GIS sooner or later in your line of work.